# React ternary operator how to call 2 functions?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, conditional-operator

How can i call two functions in a ternary operator?
I tried it by adding a && but then it does only call the first function and ignores the second.

```
e.g.
setState(date) && dispatch(paypal_error({ time: date }))
```

Here is the full code

```
const handleDateChange = (date) => {
    setDisablePing(true);
    const minutes = parseInt(dayjs(date).format('HH') * 60) +
      parseInt(dayjs(date).format('m'))

     if(minutes > pauseStartMin && minutes < pauseEndMin){
setState(
          new Date(0, 0, 0, pauseEndHour, pauseEndMinute + deliveryTime)
        ),
        dispatch(
          paypal_error({
            time: new Date(
              0,
              0,
              0,
              pauseEndHour,
              pauseEndMinute + deliveryTime
            ),
          }),
        
        toast.error(
          `Zurzeit Pause. Bestellungen ab ${dayjs(
            newPauseEndHour.toString(),
            'H'
          ).format('HH')}:${dayjs((newPauseEndMin + 1).toString(), 'm').format(
            'mm'
          )} Uhr wieder möglich`,
          {
            position: toast.POSITION.BOTTOM_RIGHT,
          }
        )
     }else{
      setState(date);
      dispatch(paypal_error({ time: date }))
     }
  };
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator).

```
(setState(date), dispatch(paypal_error({ time: date })))
```

You have JSX in your function that doesn't belong there. Remove it:

```
const handleDateChange = (date) => {
    parseInt(dayjs(date).format('HH') * 60) +
        parseInt(dayjs(date).format('m')) >
        pauseStartMin &&
        parseInt(dayjs(date).format('HH') * 60) +
        parseInt(dayjs(date).format('m')) <
        pauseEndMin ? (
        setState(new Date(0, 0, 0, pauseEndHour, pauseEndMinute + deliveryTime)),
        dispatch(paypal_error({
            time: new Date(
                0,
                0,
                0,
                pauseEndHour,
                pauseEndMinute + deliveryTime
            ),
        }))
    ) : (
        setState(date), dispatch(paypal_error({ time: date }))
    );
};
```

But you don't need the ternary operator here, just use `if-else`, it's easier to read:

```
const handleDateChange = (date) => {
    const minutes = parseInt(dayjs(date).format('HH') * 60) +
        parseInt(dayjs(date).format('m'));
    if (minutes > pauseStartMin &&
        minutes < pauseEndMin) {
        setState(new Date(0, 0, 0, pauseEndHour, pauseEndMinute + deliveryTime));
        dispatch(paypal_error({
            time: new Date(
                0,
                0,
                0,
                pauseEndHour,
                pauseEndMinute + deliveryTime
            ),
        }));
    } else {
        setState(date);
        dispatch(paypal_error({ time: date }));
    };
};
```

Comment: Im getting this error: Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression

Comment: I have updated my answer with suggestions.

Comment: Looks kinda good. Only problem I've is that I didn't send the full code before. There is also a toast.error in case if is true and now i run into error bcs format seems to be wrong...

Comment: nvm fixed it...